# Shen's Ki Strike Damage

Tags: league-of-legends

Looking on the League of Legends wiki for Shen's Abilities, I was reading Ki Strike and not clear on the wording.

> Every 8 seconds, Shen's next attack deals 10 + (5 x level) + (+8% of his bonus health) bonus magic damage. Whenever an enemy champion hits Shen with a basic attack, the cooldown is reduced by 2 seconds.

Specifically I'm unsure about how much damage we're talking about.  10 + 5 x level is easy.  But how does "8% of his bonus health" apply?  Does it mean 'bonus health' as in the health granted by in-game items/abilities?  Does it include things like runes and masteries?  Am I misunderstanding this ability completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bonus health means health gained from items / runes / masteries.

At level **18**, Shen naturally has 1958 health*, so Ki strike bonus damage is equal to (Total Health - 1958)*.08.

*Shen suffers from a reduction in health due to the [Inverse Ninja Law](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu) when Akali, Kennen, or both are on his team. This will reduce the base health of all involved by 1 or 2, giving Shen a range of base health from 1956-1958.

Comment: Inverse Ninja Law, interesting fact you found there :)

Comment: Haha, is that really true about Shen's (slightly) lowered base max health?  If so, hilarious.

Comment: You can't link to TvTropes without warning! Lives have been [ruined](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife) that way!

Comment: Originally, the Inverse Ninja Law was implemented as a reduction to their base attack damage (same magnitudes), but Riot eventually changed it to Health, as 1 attack damage is worth a lot more gold than 1 health.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, does the Inverse Ninja Law apply to Lee Sin now as well?

Comment: @TheQ Monks != Ninjas

Comment: @Raven Energy based champ is all, thanks for the info :)